# ActiveAdmin: render index table of has many resource in show page of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-7

Trying to build this with Active admin 3.0. This seems so basic to me that I feel I must be missing something.

Let's assume I have a `Store` model and an `Employee` model and a store has many employees and employees belong to a store.

When I go to the `show` page for a store, I would like, below the main section of store attributes, to have a table that lists all the employees for that store. I would literally just like to render the employees `index` as a partial or something like that and that pass it the employees for that specific store.

I don't want to custom code all of this and end up having to rewrite all the index logic and related styling and html, it seems like there should be a simpler way. Is there some one liner I can throw in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you)

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Store do

  # other code...

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :id
      row :name
      row :description
      # other rows for Store model...
    end

    panel 'Employees' do
      paginated_collection(store.employees.page(params[:page]).per(15), download_links: false) do
        table_for(collection, sortable: false) do
          column :id
          column :username
          # Other columns for the Employees table
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # other code...

end
```